# Additional condition used for filtering only on some type of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's my use-case: I 'd like to filter out all records on one condition and additionally filter out some records on additional condition.

**EDITED**

Here's the two conditions:

1. all records must met condition `created_at > SYSDATE + 30`
2. records from the table **users** that have (share) the same id as in the table **blacklist** (`join on u.id = b.id`) where the column **endpoint** is equal to `XYZ` must have column **delayed_until** that meets criterion `older than now`. If **endpoint** is not equal to `XYZ`, only 1st condition applies.

I have come up with the following query:

```
SELECT    * users u 
left join blacklist b 
ON        u.id = b.id 
AND       b.delayed_until < SYSDATE 
AND       u.endpoint = 'XYZ' 
WHERE     u.created_at > SYSDATE + 30;
```

Here's my schema (simplified):

[image]

Does my query do what intended? Can it be rewritten so that it is faster? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u JOIN
     blacklist b 
     ON u.id = b.id AND
        (b.delayed_until <= SYSDATE OR
         u.endpoint <> 'XYZ'
        )      
WHERE u.created_at > SYSDATE + 30;
```

Filtering on the first table in the `ON` clause doesn't make sense with a `LEFT JOIN`.

For this query, you want indexes on `users(endpoint, created_at, id)` and `blacklist(id, delayed_until)`.

Comment: Does this query find all endpoints and not only these that are equal to `XYZ`. I'd like to all endpoints. Please see my updated question with some clarifications.

Comment: @menteith . . . I modified the query based on your comment.  I think you just want an inner join rather than an outer join.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why you used `(b.delayed_until <= SYSDATE OR u.endpoint <> 'XYZ' ) `?

Comment: @menteith . . . I think that implements the logic "where the column endpoint is equal to XYZ must have column delayed_until".